# How can i move my marker continuosly in the google maps while using useEffect and redux

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, websocket, react-redux, use-effect

So, in my project I need to use google maps inorder to track the live position. I was getting the live coordinates with the socket connection from the backend and I stored them in the redux store variable.
Now my problem is how can I change the marker continuosly for each new coordinate while using the useEffect hook ? At first I thought of re-rendering the map each time I get an new coordinate, but you might have guessed  what happened next.The application broke due to continuos re-rendering. So, how can I change it?

Comment: Why would continuous rerendering occur with live updates? How frequent are your updates?

Comment: Since I have to share the live location update continuosly just like uber. I get new coordinates for every two seconds